# Improving my question about who is or will be in heaven

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I recently asked the following question:
[According to Baptists: Which persons are known to be (eventually) in heaven?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79506)

The original version of the question was not this specific about a Christian group and was thus closed; after edits, it was re-opened. For comparison, the original question:
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/revisions/79506/1

I understand why it was closed, different Christian groups have different understandings of Bible verses and of who is or will be in heaven.
In the comments it is suggested to narrow the Christian group further down, but I think the question could be improved in another way - but I need help doing so.
My original goal of the question was to ask a bible-centered question, independent of Christian groups. For example, the verse

> And he said to him, “Truly, I say to you, today you will be with me in paradise.”
> **Luke 23:43 (ESV)**

objectively states, that someone is (or was) in paradise. How certain Christian groups understand the verse was originally not an intended target of the question.

There are other questions, which are as Bible-centered as I'd like my question to be. Two examples:

- [What is the ultimate goal of a human according to Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79425/)
- [Who are innocent people according to Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16279/)

As I wrote in the comments, a benefit of such a question would be, that the answers can be used 'library'-like by any Christian (group).

I know, that ["Are there any verses"-questions are considered open ended questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6935/51103). But I think my question can be changed towards a different category. E.g. a question like "Which Bible verses mention the word 'Toledot' (תּוֹלְדֹת‎)" would have an objectively correct and concrete answer. Is there any way to change my question, so that objectivity can be reached?

The main challenge for improving this question is in my opinion to define an objective criterion, whether to name a personage and Bible quote.

In summary: (How) can my question be altered towards fitting the Q&A format and being objective and independent of Christian groups? Should I move the question to [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Neither of the Bible-centred questions you link to there are exemplary questions for this site, and I have strongly considered closing both. If you haven't read it, please read [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)

Comment: Ultimately I don't think there's a good way forward for your question. Only God knows the true salvation state of any person. You'll have to wait till you reach heaven/the resurrection to find out who else made it!

Comment: @curiousdannii Sorry, if I wasn't clear (2nd language English). I agree, that only God knows the true salvation state. My goal was not a comprehensive list of all Biblical personages (eventually) in heaven. It was a list of all Biblical personages, for whom it was written in the Bible. Then, ultimately, do you know a better place for the question? Biblical Hermeneutics?

Comment: It would definitely be off-topic on Biblical Hermeneutics. You could ask if any denominations have attempted to compile such a list, or alternatively instead of asking for a list, ask how a denomination reasons about salvation for people before Christ and whether they think they can definitively say whether someone was saved or not. The first is a denomination-survey question, so doesn't need to be scoped, the second option should really be scoped I think. Maybe an overview could work, though I doubt you'd get an answer. (Overview questions are hard and this is somewhat obscure a topic!)

Comment: Thank you, I like your first idea! I edited the question, hope it is still fitting for this site.